# How to detect duplicate between input and output file and prevent adding duplicate items into output file in python?

Tags: python

I am writing a python program to manage the user accounts in FreeRadius server.If I don't want to add any duplicate accounts in the output file
(users.conf).How can I change the code in adduser command(for creating single account) and au command(for importing files to create multiple accounts)?

The username consists of 5-digit numbers in the first word in the rows.I don't want it being duplicated in output file after creating user account.

- Preferred Output file:
- 81045     User-Password == "81045"
- 56811     User-Password == "56811"
- 56287     User-Password == "56287"
- 65654     User-Password == "65654"
- 99737     User-Password == "99737"
- 56185     User-Password == "56185"
- I don't want this output happen:
- 81045     User-Password == "81045"
- 81045     User-Password == "56811"
- 65654     User-Password == "56287"
- 65654     User-Password == "65654"
- 99737     User-Password == "99737"
- 56185     User-Password == "56185"

  ```
    def adduser():
    with open('C:/FreeRADIUS.net/etc/raddb/users.conf', "r+") as fh:
    completed_lines = set()
    for line in open('C:/FreeRADIUS.net/etc/raddb/users.conf', "r"):
      if createuserentry.get() and createuserpwd.set() not in completed_lines:
         fh.write('\n')
         fh.write(createuserentry.get() + "     " + "User-Password == " + '"' + createuserpwd.get() + '"')
         fh.write('\n')
         fh.close()
         tkMessageBox.showinfo("success", "Account created")
      else:
          fh.close()
          tkMessageBox.showinfo("Failure", "Username is duplicated")



  def au():
  au.filename = tkFileDialog.askopenfilename(initialdir = "/",title = "Select file to open",filetypes = (("txt","*.txt"),("all files","*.*")))
  print(au.filename)
  completed_lines_hash = set()
  with open('C:/FreeRADIUS.net/etc/raddb/users.conf', 'a') as output_file:
     with open(au.filename, "r") as input_file:
  for line in open(au.filename, "r"):
      hashValue = hashlib.md5(line.rstrip().encode('utf+8')).hexdigest()
      if hashValue not in completed_lines_hash:
          output_file.write(line)
          completed_lines_hash.add(hashValue)

   output_file.close()  
   tkMessageBox.showinfo("success", "Accounts created and all duplicate items are ignored")


  def deleteuser():
  with open('C:/FreeRADIUS.net/etc/raddb/users.conf', "r") as fh:
  lines = fh.readlines()
  with open('C:/FreeRADIUS.net/etc/raddb/users.conf', "w") as fh:
  for line in lines:                  
      if deleteuserentry.get() in line and  deleteuserpwd.get() == "Pa$$w0rd123" :
         tkMessageBox.showinfo("success", "Account Deleted")
         end()



  def du():
  du.filename = tkFileDialog.askopenfilename(initialdir = "/",title = "Select file",filetypes = (("text document","*.txt"),("all files","*.*")))
  print(du.filename)
  with open(du.filename, "r") as input_file:
  with open('C:/FreeRADIUS.net/etc/raddb/users.conf', 'w+') as output_file:
  for line in input_file:
      if "User" in line: continue
      output_file.write()

  output_file.close() 
  tkMessageBox.showinfo("success", "Accounts deleted")
  ```

Comment: Sounds like you should be using a DB of some sort (for example, `sqlite3`), not a file.

Comment: I agree with @goodvibration, it is better to use a DB for this purpose. Is there any specific reason you don't want to? Or, may be you could even use a .csv file and manipulate it using "pandas" package

Comment: you have wrong comparision - you have to check `if (createuserentry.get() not in completed_lines) and (createuserpwd.get() not in completed_lines):`